# Spanning RAID over SSD and Mechanical HD

Tags: linux, hard-disk, raid, mdadm, ssd

Currently I have my `root` (`/`) directory on my ssd, and my home directory on my mechanical drive. Wanting to utilize more of the ssd and hopefully get a speed benefit, I was considering spanning across the two with software raid. (Hybrid style).

Does anyone have any experience doing this? I'm really not finding much info on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without problems, assuming you're talking about RAID1. Create the RAID1 with e.g `mdadm --create --level 1 -n 2 /dev/mdX /dev/sdaX --write-mostly /dev/sdbX`

The `--write-mostly` tells mdadm that the following devices are slower to access and hence mostly only to be written to (or put another way: mostly read from the other device(s) which is your SSD and hence the fastest for reading; writes will always occur to both devices of course).

Comment: This is not entirely how a hybrid solution would be expected to work, but nevertheless it still sounds like a useful suggestion which I will keep in mind for next time I need to configure a redundant setup.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid style would be `dm-cache` or `bcache` or similar. RAID can be done with `--write-mostly`. But what you really want to do is just put your `/home/user/` on your SSD already. SSD should be the primary drive for everything, and HDD the secondary drive for clunky stuff (mounted elsewhere or in `/home/user/HDD/`).